# pgfplotstable with 'create on use'-statements inside resizebox is not sized correctly and looks non centered

Tags: pgfplotstable

I use pgfplotstable to create my tables from .csv-files in the following manner:

Pgfplotstable first creates some columns by merging two columns of the input table and putting a `$\pm$` in between the entries of the two initial columns.

`NaN` fields are replaced by `\ensuremath{-}`

The problem I'm having is, that I need to resize some of these tables, hence wrapping them inside a `\resizebox` statement. However the `\resizebox` is not working as expected - probably because of the `create on use` statements. It looks like as if `\resizebox` sees additional "invisible" columns infront of the actual first column hence making the table smaller then needed. The table therefore looks as if it is right aligned and not centered.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

%Make rows higher:
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.4pt}

%GLOBAL FORMATING:
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
                use comma,
                1000 sep={}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Name,1,1_err,2,2_err,3,3_err,4,4_err,5
A,10.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,3.42
B,11.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
C,12.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
D,13.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
E,14.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
F,15.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
G,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,23.3,90.23,nan
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Some text describing the table}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval-1}% <---"\N" equals the index of the last row
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\M}{\pgfplotsretval}% <---"\M" equals the total number of rows

\resizebox*{\textwidth}{!}{\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
%------------------CREATING NEW COLUMNS:-------------------------------
    create on use/one/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "one" out of columns 1 and 1_err of the input file
        create col/assign/.code={%
           \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{1}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{1_err}}}
           \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
        },
    },
    create on use/two/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "two" out of columns 2 and 2_err of the input file
      create col/assign/.code={%
         \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{2}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{2_err}}}
         \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
      },
    },
    create on use/three/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "three" out of columns 3 and 3_err of the input file
      create col/assign/.code={%
         \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[sci, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{3}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[sci, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{3_err}}}
         \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
      },
    },
    create on use/four/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "four" out of columns 4 and 4_err of the input file
      create col/assign/.code={%
         \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=1]{\thisrow{4}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=1]{\thisrow{4_err}}}
         \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
      },
    },
    %
%------------------END CREATING NEW COLUMNS-------------------------------
    columns={Name, one, two, three, four, 5},% <---these columns will appear in the table
    %
%------------------TYPESETTING COLUMNS:-------------------------------
     columns/Name/.style={% <---style column "Name"
      string type,%
      column type/.add={|}{|},%
    },
    %
    columns/one/.style={% <---style column "one"
      column name=I,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/two/.style={% <---style column "two"
      column name=II,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/three/.style={% <---style column "three"
      column name=III,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/four/.style={% <---style column "four"
      column name=IV,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces every cell with "-" except of the last cell
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/5/.style={% <---style column "5"
      column name=V,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
      assign cell content/.code={% <---first cell is put inside multirow by the length of \M hence the length of the table
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
        {\multirow{\M}{*}{\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, zerofill, precision=2}\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}}}%
        \else 
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
        \fi},
    },
    %
%------------------TYPESETTING ROWS-------------------------------
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline, after row=\hline\hline},%
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline}%
    ]%
{data.csv}}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]



\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

If I don't put the newly created columns inside the table, `resizebox` works as expected:
[image]

The code for generating this output would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  

%Make rows higher:
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.4pt}
%GLOBAL FORMATING:
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
                use comma,
                1000 sep={}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Name,1,1_err,2,2_err,3,3_err,4,4_err,5
A,10.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,3.42
B,11.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
C,12.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
D,13.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
E,14.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
F,15.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
G,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,23.3,90.23,nan
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Some text describing the table}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval-1}% <---"\N" equals the index of the last row
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\M}{\pgfplotsretval}% <---"\M" equals the total number of rows

\resizebox*{\textwidth}{!}{\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    columns={Name, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},% <---these columns will appear in the table
    %
     columns/Name/.style={% <---style column "Name"
      string type,%
      column type/.add={|}{|},%
    },
    %
    columns/1/.style={% <---style column "1"
      column name=I,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/2/.style={% <---style column "2"
      column name=II,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/3/.style={% <---style column "3"
      column name=III,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces every cell with "-" except of the last cell
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/4/.style={% <---style column "4"
      column name=IV,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={%
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi
       },
    },
    %
    columns/5/.style={% <---style column "5"
      column name=V,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
      assign cell content/.code={% <---first cell is put inside multirow by the length of \M hence the length of the table
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
        {\multirow{\M}{*}{\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, zerofill, precision=2}\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}}}%
        \else 
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
        \fi},
    },
    %
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline, after row=\hline\hline},%
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline}%
    ]%
{data.csv}}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]



\end{document}
```

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the smallest thing causes the most disappointing debugging issues.

Anyways, it needs more `%`-cowbells (wherever you see `/.code` handler look at the line ends. There are about 10 locations I've added. The easiest is making a diff to see). Then it works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

%Make rows higher:
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.4pt}

%GLOBAL FORMATING:
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
                use comma,
                1000 sep={}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Name,1,1_err,2,2_err,3,3_err,4,4_err,5
A,10.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,3.42
B,11.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
C,12.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
D,13.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
E,14.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
F,15.23,3.23,23.32,13.23,0.000123,0.00000123,nan,nan,nan
G,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,23.3,90.23,nan
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Some text describing the table}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval-1}% <---"\N" equals the index of the last row
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\M}{\pgfplotsretval}% <---"\M" equals the total number of rows

\resizebox*{\textwidth}{!}{\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
%------------------CREATING NEW COLUMNS:-------------------------------
    create on use/one/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "one" out of columns 1 and 1_err of the input file
        create col/assign/.code={%
           \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{1}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{1_err}}}%
           \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
        },
    },
    create on use/two/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "two" out of columns 2 and 2_err of the input file
      create col/assign/.code={%
         \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{2}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{2_err}}}%
         \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
      },
    },
    create on use/three/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "three" out of columns 3 and 3_err of the input file
      create col/assign/.code={%
         \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[sci, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{3}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[sci, zerofill, precision=2]{\thisrow{3_err}}}%
         \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
      },
    },
    create on use/four/.style={% <---create and typeset new column "four" out of columns 4 and 4_err of the input file
      create col/assign/.code={%
         \edef\entry{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=1]{\thisrow{4}}$\pm$\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=1]{\thisrow{4_err}}}%
         \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}%
      },
    },
    %
%------------------END CREATING NEW COLUMNS-------------------------------
    columns={Name, one, two, three, four, 5},% <---these columns will appear in the table
    %
%------------------TYPESETTING COLUMNS:-------------------------------
     columns/Name/.style={% <---style column "Name"
      string type,%
      column type/.add={|}{|},%
    },
    %
    columns/one/.style={% <---style column "one"
      column name=I,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi%
       },
    },
    %
    columns/two/.style={% <---style column "two"
      column name=II,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi%
       },
    },
    %
    columns/three/.style={% <---style column "three"
      column name=III,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces last cell with "-"
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi%
       },
    },
    %
    columns/four/.style={% <---style column "four"
      column name=IV,
      string type, column type/.add={}{|},%
      postproc cell content/.append code={% <---replaces every cell with "-" except of the last cell
       \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<\N%
         \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\ensuremath{-}}\fi%
       },
    },
    %
    columns/5/.style={% <---style column "5"
      column name=V,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
      assign cell content/.code={% <---first cell is put inside multirow by the length of \M hence the length of the table
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0%
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
        {\multirow{\M}{*}{\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, zerofill, precision=2}\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}}}%
        \else% 
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
        \fi},
    },
    %
%------------------TYPESETTING ROWS-------------------------------
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline, after row=\hline\hline},%
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline}%
    ]%
{data.csv}}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I would never have found this. I already looked for some ugly workaround involving `\usepackage{changepage}` etc. Thank you!

Comment: @Wamseln My pleasure.